# How to enlarge one photo on hover in photo gallery and reduce size of other images in the gallery so that the enlarged one takes up their space?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm using wordpress with elementor pro plugin. I'm new to programming so my question is :
Let say I would like to have gallery 4 (columns) x 20 (rows) of images. When I hover an image with mouse, I need the picture to enalrge and take space of for example 2 or 3 images next to it and below it/above it in the gallery. The other images in the column needs to reduce their size when the cursor is on enlarged photo. I want to achieve this effect on every photo in gallery when it is hovered. Is it possible to do this only with CSS or do I have to use JavaScript.

Sorry for the long question.

I would really appreciate your answer,
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey it is simple as you can do it directly in css using the

**:hover**
and can specify the increased width in it for that image whereas you can set other images

**width:auto**

By doing this the other images will shrink as one image enlarges on hover.

**Hope It Helps!!**

Comment: Than you so much for your quick answer. I'm going to try it when i finish making the gallery.